# I'm using Ajax to populate my web page, but the populated HTML isn't working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, xml, ajax

I'm using Ajax to dynamically populate a DIV. I have each page content stored in XML files as CDATA. When a user clicks on a link from the navigation bar, the Ajax loads the XML for that particular page, parses it, and populates the DIV with it's content.

Everything is working GREAT, except for one thing. I have a jQuery modal popup whose markup is loaded from that page's XML file. The .js and .css files from the jQuery plugin are all loaded, and when this is HARD CODED (i.e., not loaded from XML), it works fine. But when it's loaded from the XML, the modal doesn't work.

When the page is loaded from the XML file- What the page is supposed to do is load the HTML from the XML file, which it does, and there's a hyperlink that when clicked, it's supposed to create the modal popup window. Instead, clicking on the link does NOT fire up the modal popup window.

When the page is hard coded- it does everything it's supposed to do.

A live example is at:

http://mikemarks.net/clientSites/tabras/

Click on "The Band", and at the bottom you'll see the hyperlink called "Demo". Clicking on that should bring up a modal popup window, but instead as you can see it just takes you to the top of the page.

Below is my markup (notice the div id="copy", which is the placeholder for my HTML content that's loaded from the XML file), my Ajax JavaScript code, and my XML file (which is shown as the markup that's loaded into the div id="copy").

```
<div id="leftTwoThirdsColumn">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li style="width:65px;"><a id="default" href="#" onclick="makeRequest('xml/default.xml');"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                    <li style="width:65px;"><a id="lyrics" href="#" onclick="makeRequest('xml/lyrics.xml');"><span>Lyrics</span></a></li>
                    <li style="width:110px;"><a id="merch" href="#" onclick="makeRequest('xml/merch.xml');"><span>Merchandise</span></a></li>
                    <li style="width:93px;"><a id="bio" href="#" onclick="makeRequest('xml/bio.xml');"><span>The Band</span></a></li>
                    <li style="width:80px;"><a id="contact" href="#" onclick="makeRequest('xml/contact.xml');"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                    <li style="width:150px;" class="last"><a id="friends" href="#" onclick="makeRequest('xml/friends.xml');"><span>Friends of Tabr&auml;s</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br /><br />

            <div id="copy">

            </div>
        </div>
```

```
function makeRequest(url) 
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        request = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    }
```

```
sendRequest(url);
```

}

function sendRequest(url)
{
    request.onreadystatechange = onResponse;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function checkReadyState(obj)
{
    if(obj.readyState == 0) { document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Sending Request..."; }
    if(obj.readyState == 1) { document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Loading Response..."; }
    if(obj.readyState == 2) { document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Response Loaded..."; }
    if(obj.readyState == 3) { document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "Response Ready..."; }
    if(obj.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(obj.status == 200)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(obj.status == 404)
        {
            // Add a custom message or redirect the user to another page
            document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "File not found";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = "There was a problem retrieving the XML.";
        }
    }
}

function onResponse() 
{
    if(checkReadyState(request)) {
        var response = request.responseXML.documentElement;
        var root = new Array();
        root = response.getElementsByTagName('*');
        //alert("Total Number of HTML Elements Found: " + response.getElementsByTagName("*").length);
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
            var tagName = response.getElementsByTagName("*").item(i).nodeName;
            var tagObj = response.getElementsByTagName("*").item(i);
            html += tagObj.firstChild.nodeValue;
        }
        document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = html;
    }
}

<div style="padding-top:5px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">
    <img src="images/ShawnBioActive.png" />
    <img src="images/JasonBioActive.png" />
    <img src="images/WillBioActive.png" />
    <img src="images/RasoulBioActive.png" />
    <img src="images/bioStrip.png" />
    <div id='basic-modal'><h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3><p>A basic modal dialog with minimal styling and no additional options. There are a few CSS attributes set internally by SimpleModal, however, SimpleModal relies mostly on style options and/or external CSS for the look and feel.</p><input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic'/> or <a href='#' class='basic'>Demo</a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modal/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modal/basic.js"></script><link type="text/css" href="../css/modal/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" /><link type="text/css" href="../css/modal/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" /><script type='text/javascript'>jQuery().ready(function () {$('#basic-modal-content').modal();});</script>
    <div id="basic-modal-content"><h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3></div><div style='display:none'><img src='images/modal/basic/x.png' alt='' /></div></test2>
  </div>

Comment: You have a mix-mash of jquery and *something else*, stuff like this shouldn't exist if you're using jquery: `onclick="makeRequest('xml/default.xml');`, or `request = new XMLHttpRequest();`
, or even `document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML`... What tutorials have you been reading? jQuery does a lot of really smart things such that you don't have to spent time screwing around with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your webpage lacks of jquery.simplemodal.js and basic.js and the css associated ( for example, for the display:none; on your *basic-modal-content* )

That's why you don't have any modal on load.

Plus, your link or button doesn't have any event handler (for example,  $('.basic').click(...);)

That's why you don't have any other action than the anchor.

To remove the anchor action, I recommand to use [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Yeah that's weird, because everything was working perfectly when it was hard coded. The "#" anchor is how it is in the raw form, off of the modal example I got off of jQuery's website, and it worked as it is now.  Yeah about the lacking of the .js files, my bad, but even when they are included it displays the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. It is moving you to the top because you have a href="#" change it to href="javascript:void(0)"
2. http://mikemarks.net/clientSites/js/modal/jquery.simplemodal.js  returns 404. Check location
3. http://mikemarks.net/clientSites/js/modal/basic.js returns 404. Check location